# Symfony2 : how to check if an action is secured?

Tags: php, security, symfony

I would like to check from inside a controller if it is a secured page or not.
How to do this ?

My use case is the following :

- User can register and log in
- If he logs in and tries to access a secured page, he will be redirected to a "beta version" page until the end of June.
- If he tries to access a normal page (not secured), he will be able to access it without any redirection.

Thanks for your help !

Aurel

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve. When user types URL (or is being redirected to) action **that action is either secured or is not secured**. Controllers can't have multiple actions (secured and not secured) with same name, because of method name, obviously. You could however ask SecureContext if visiting user has corresponding role and then do something with request (e.g. forward, redirect)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When Symfony2 processes a request it matches the url pattern with each firewall defined in `app/config/security.yml`. When url pattern matches with a pattern of the firewall Symfony2 creates some listener objects and call `handle` method of those objects. If any listener returns a `Response` object then the loop breaks and Symfony2 outputs the response. Authentication part is done in authentication listeners. They are created from config defined in matched firewall e.g `form_login`, `http_basic` etc. If user is not authenticated then authenticated listeners create a `RedirectResponse` object to redirect user to login page. For your case, you can *cheat* by creating a custom authentication listener and add it in your secured page firewall. Sample implementation would be following,

Create a `Token` class,

```
namespace Your\Namespace;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AbstractToken;

class MyToken extends AbstractToken
{
    public function __construct(array $roles = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($roles);
    }

    public function getCredentials()
    {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Create a class that implements `AuthenticationProviderInterface`. For `form_login` listener it authenticates with the given `UserProvider`. In this case it will do nothing.

```
namespace Your\Namespace;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\AuthenticationProviderInterface;
use Acme\BaseBundle\Firewall\MyToken;

class MyAuthProvider implements AuthenticationProviderInterface
{

    public function authenticate(TokenInterface $token)
    {
        if (!$this->supports($token)) {
            return null;
        }

        throw new \Exception('you should not get here');
    }

    public function supports(TokenInterface $token)
    {
        return $token instanceof MyToken;
    }
```

Create an entry point class. The listener will create a `RedirectResponse` from this class.

```
namespace Your\Namespace;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\EntryPoint\AuthenticationEntryPointInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\HttpUtils;


class MyAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPointInterface
{
    private $httpUtils;
    private $redirectPath;

    public function __construct(HttpUtils $httpUtils, $redirectPath)
    {
        $this->httpUtils = $httpUtils;
        $this->redirectPath = $redirectPath;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null)
    {
        //redirect action goes here
        return $this->httpUtils->createRedirectResponse($request, $this->redirectPath);
    }
```

Create a listener class. Here you will implement your redirection logic.

```
namespace Your\Namespace;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ListenerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\EntryPoint\AuthenticationEntryPointInterface;

class MyAuthenticationListener implements ListenerInterface
{
    private $securityContext;
    private $authenticationEntryPoint;


    public function __construct(SecurityContextInterface $securityContext, AuthenticationEntryPointInterface $authenticationEntryPoint)
    {
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
        $this->authenticationEntryPoint = $authenticationEntryPoint;
    }

    public function handle(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $token = $this->securityContext->getToken();
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        if($token === null){
            return;
        }

        //add your logic
        $redirect = // boolean value based on your logic

        if($token->isAuthenticated() && $redirect){

            $response = $this->authenticationEntryPoint->start($request);
            $event->setResponse($response);
            return;
        }
    }

}
```

Create the services.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

    <services>

        <service id="my_firewall.security.authentication.listener"
                 class="Your\Namespace\MyAuthenticationListener"
                 parent="security.authentication.listener.abstract"
                 abstract="true">
            <argument type="service" id="security.context" />
            <argument /> <!-- Entry Point -->
        </service>

        <service id="my_firewall.entry_point" class="Your\Namespace\MyAuthenticationEntryPoint" public="false" ></service>

        <service id="my_firewall.auth_provider" class="Your\Namespace\MyAuthProvider" public="false"></service>
    </services>

</container>
```

Register the listener. Create a folder named `Security/Factory` in your bundles `DependencyInjection` folder. Then create the factory class.

```
namespace Your\Bundle\DependencyInjection\Security\Factory;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\DefinitionDecorator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition;
use Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\DependencyInjection\Security\Factory\SecurityFactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\NodeDefinition;

class MyFirewallFactory implements SecurityFactoryInterface
{

    public function create(ContainerBuilder $container, $id, $config, $userProvider, $defaultEntryPoint)
    {
        $provider = 'my_firewall.auth_provider.'.$id;
        $container->setDefinition($provider, new DefinitionDecorator('my_firewall.auth_provider'));

        // entry point
        $entryPointId = $this->createEntryPoint($container, $id, $config, $defaultEntryPoint);

        // listener
        $listenerId = 'my_firewall.security.authentication.listener'.$id;
        $listener = $container->setDefinition($listenerId, new DefinitionDecorator('my_firewall.security.authentication.listener'));
        $listener->replaceArgument(1, new Reference($entryPointId));
        return array($provider, $listenerId, $entryPointId);
    }

    public function getPosition()
    {
        return 'pre_auth';
    }

    public function getKey()
    {
        return 'my_firewall'; //the listener name
    }

    protected function getListenerId()
    {
        return 'my_firewall.security.authentication.listener';
    }

    public function addConfiguration(NodeDefinition $node)
    {
        $node
            ->children()
                ->scalarNode('redirect_path')->end()
            ->end()
            ;
    }

    protected function createEntryPoint($container, $id, $config, $defaultEntryPointId)
    {
        $entryPointId = 'my_firewall.entry_point'.$id;
        $container
            ->setDefinition($entryPointId, new DefinitionDecorator('my_firewall.entry_point'))
            ->addArgument(new Reference('security.http_utils'))
            ->addArgument($config['redirect_path'])
            ;
        return $entryPointId;
    }

}
```

Then in your `NamespaceBundle.php` of your bundle folder add the following code.

```
public function build(ContainerBuilder $builder){
    parent::build($builder);
    $extension = $builder->getExtension('security');
    $extension->addSecurityListenerFactory(new Security\Factory\MyFirewallFactory());
}
```

Authentication listener is created, phew :). Now in your `app/config/security.yml` do following.

```
api_area:
  pattern: ^/secured/
  provider: fos_userbundle
  form_login:
    check_path: /login_check
    login_path: /login
    csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
  my_firewall:
    redirect_path: /beta
  logout: true
  anonymous: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is the correct method 
But you can try the following

/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php has a method *handleRaw* that converts a request to a response . The request object is accessable from there . You can check if the client has requested to access the secured page . If so , you can manually set the controller like

```
$request->attributes->set('_controller','your\Bundle\SecureBundle\Controller\SecureController::secureAction');
```

Another solution would be to set a session if the user try to access a secured page and check for the same inside your controller

Again , this might not be the correct method but it is a possible workaround